# Java "get{Object}" method naming convention

Tags: java, android, coding-style, naming-conventions

Which of the following is compliant with Java guidelines?

```
Observable<List<Account>> getAccounts(String userId);

Observable<List<Account>> getAccountsForUser(String userId);
```

I don't want to start a debate, I'm looking for a document that is stating the guidelines. I don't think it matters, but I'm using the previous snippet of code inside an Android project.

Comment: Opinion-based. You could even think of a `Observable<List<Account>> getAccountsFor(String userId)`...

Comment: There's no one official guideline. Details like this are left to individual companies/projects to define -- or even to individual developers, since this is a _really_ small detail.

Comment: It's up to you really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say if there is only 1 type of model that has "accounts" then use

```
Observable<List<Account>> getAccounts(String userId);
```

If there are multiple models that have accounts, then it makes sense to define the method in more detail by using:

```
Observable<List<Account>> getAccountsForUser(String userId);
```